# Storing variable number of values of something in a database

Tags: php, mysql, metaprogramming, methodology

I'm developing a QA web-app which will have some points to evaluated assigned to one of the following Categories.

- Call management
- Technical skills
- Ticket management

As this aren't likely to change it's not worth making them dynamic but the worst point is that points are like to.

First I had a table of 'quality' which had a column for each point but then requisites changed and I'm kinda blocked.

I have to store "evaluations" that have all points with their values but maybe, in the future, those points will change.

I thought that in the quality table I could make some kind of string that have something like that

```
1=1|2=1|3=2
```

Where you have sets of ID of point and punctuation of that given value.

Can someone point me to a better method to do that?

Comment: Why not store that relation in other table[s]?

Comment: I'm not sure of what do you mean. It's supposed that a evaluation should have all possible valuable points inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table is not normalized. It violates [1st Normal Form (1NF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form):

```
Evaluation
----------------------------------------
EvaluationId | List Of point=punctuation
   1         |   1=1|2=1|3=2
   2         |   1=5|2=6|3=7
```

You can read more about [Database Normalization basics](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm). 
The table could be normalized as:

```
Evaluation
-------------
EvaluationId 
   1         
   2         

Quality
---------------------------------------
EvaluationId | Point | Punctuation
   1         |   1   |   1   
   1         |   2   |   1
   1         |   3   |   2 
   2         |   1   |   5  
   2         |   2   |   6
   2         |   3   |   7
```

Comment: I thought about that but this would lead to, 20 inserted rows foreach evaluation if I have 20 evaluation points. Is that optimized?

Comment: Yes, this is better because it's easier to maintain, query, update, enforce constraints, etc. This is standard database design.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned many times here on SO, NEVER PUT MORE THAN ONE VALUE INTO A DB FIELD, IF YOU WANT TO ACCESS THEM SEPERATELY.

So I suggest to have 2 additional tables:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO categories VALUES (1,"Call management"),(2,"Technical skills"),(3,"Ticket management");
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE qualities (id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, category int NOT NULL, punctuation int NOT nULL)
```

then store and query your data accordingly